# Facebook wall post with object attachment using iOS SDK 3.5.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Facebook recently changed its publish API to prevent post on another user's wall and we should use their share dialogue.

[Facebook documentation about publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/)

I need to share a photo to my friend's wall and I could achieve this using /USER_ID/feed post by specifying a post parameter named object_attachment. Now they have removed /USER_ID/feed post on another user's wall.

So my chances are to follow their share dialogue. But share dialogue will not accept object_attachment parameter of any kind and I can not share photo to my friend's wall or timeline.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

As you rightly mentioned, Facebook have removed the ability to post via the graph API to another user's feed.

You can, however, use their `FB.ui({ method: 'feed' })` [feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) Javascript dialog combined with `target_id:` to prompt the user to post to one of their friends' walls.

The accepted parameters are listed on the [documentation page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and no, you can't attach anything.

One alternative is to create a unique resource for each photo you would have uploaded which contains [open graph meta tags](http://ogp.me/), with which you can describe a thumbnail (`og:image` and `og:image:secure_url`).

Another alternative is to [upload the photo to the current user's album](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/), then to [tag the user's friend in that photo](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/):

```
//Tag friend_to_tag_id at position (x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"
    .$photo_id . "/tags/" . $friend_to_tag_id 
    . "?access_token=". $access_token
    . "&x=" . $x_coordinate . "&y=" . $y_coordinate . "&method=POST";
$response = file_get_contents($post_url);
```

Comment: Tagging is not an good option for me. I want to share a greeting to my friend through FB. So post should be in friend's wall not mine. In order to create thumbnail I might need to upload image to server and pass this url to fb. It won't be good option for me as I have a large user space. Any other alternatives?

Comment: This is the extent of the Facebook API available for the functionality you need, as far as I know, I'm afraid.